# XML layout is different once loaded

Tags: android, xml, layout

I've a layout with a 16 buttons, every button has an image and a textview under the image.
I've this buttons in a particular order,but once is loaded in the activity the order is not the last i've edited but remain the previous!
Why in the editor of eclipse is correct and on runtime is different?!?
Thanks!

Comment: try this: **right click on your project->Run Configuration** run from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes a clean and rebuild is enough to solve your problem. Also you will get a warning on your XML preview that you need to build your project if you changed any code in a custom view for it to draw it properly.

Comment: Yep,this is the solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall previous app from your android device (if compiling from android device).

Then Go to  Project->Clean . Then run your project .

Answer (score 0):

First of all Uninstall  the application from your device .
go to **Project > Clean**. then you can run your project again 
it will be remove your error **strong text**